# Console.log comes and goes upon submission in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have one small problem in my code that I can't seem to figure out.

```
  (function($){

        var FormLoanView = Backbone.View.extend({
          tagName: 'div',
          template: _.template('<form> Annual Income: <input></input> <br> Monthly Payment: <input></input> <br> Down Payment: <input></input> <br> APR: <input></input><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>'),
          initialize: function(){
            var $data = this.$el.html(this.template())
            $('body').html($data)
          },
          events:{
            'submit': 'checking'
          },
          checking: function(){
            console.log("button clicked")
          }


        })


         $(document).ready(function () {

          var LoanView = new FormLoanView({
          });

        });
       })(jQuery);
```

So when I click submit on my input button I expect to see "button clicked". When using chrome developer tools, I am able to see the console log, but for some reason it appears and disappears. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: What is the default action of a form submission?

Comment: yeah looks like the form is doing a page refresh hence why the console.log disappears.

Comment: That's because submitting a form, well, submits the form to the server unless you tell it otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments have already mentioned, you are capturing the submit event but you don't prevent its default behaviour (to send a GET request to the server with the form data appended as parameters).

To stop the page refreshing due to this request you can call [`e.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) in your `checking()` method.

```
    var FormLoanView = Backbone.View.extend({
      ...
      initialize: function(){
        var $data = this.$el.html(this.template())
        $('body').html($data)
      },
      events:{
        'submit': 'checking'
      },
      checking: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("button clicked")
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. preventDefault is awesome.